# What is the maximum contract size limit for frontier EVM smart contract?

Tags: frontier, evm, frontier-node-template

Does the contract limit size information shown in the link below holds true for Frontier EVM also?
https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/smart-contracts/#limitations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the same as the main Ethereum chain (it follows all the ETH standards, so also EIP 170). The Frontier pallets are however configurable so you can change some parameters that allow you to change the `BlockGasLimit` which has an impact on the contract limit size.